# Swipe left to delete Listview row or Item in android

Tags: android, listview

As I know there is an option to display delete button in a list view, if user swipe the item to left in IOS by default.
I want to implement it in android as well. How can I do this? i.e. is this option available in android as well?

Comment: There is no option like same as in IOS but you need to design custom layout. can you please check swipe to delete functionality in listview

Comment: https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView try this one

Comment: @Chanika https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo, there are a lot of examples. Try googling first

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard feature, however the EnhandedListView library provides a ListView with swipe-to-dissmiss functionality (in any direction you'd like) and also an undo function. You'll find the library here https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView and you can download a demo app from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.timroes.android.listviewdemo

Comment: if this link will help, you need to post some of the content which it deals instead of simply posting the link.